# How to set dynamic configuration using push refresh in a Java Spring app

Tags: java, azure, azure-web-app-service

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/enable-dynamic-configuration-java-spring-push-refresh?tabs=spring-boot-3%2Ccmd , I have to use this app properties (below). Can I not specify push-notification properties (Assume I don't know myToken and myTokenSecret )?

```
# Azure App Configuration Properties
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].connection-string= ${AppConfigurationConnectionString}
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].monitoring.enabled= true
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].monitoring.refresh-interval= 30d
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].monitoring.triggers[0].key= sentinel
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].monitoring.push-notification.primary-token.name= myToken
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].monitoring.push-notification.primary-token.secret= myTokenSecret

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include= appconfiguration-refresh
```

Answer (score 0):

```
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].monitoring.push-notification.primary-token.name= myToken
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].monitoring.push-notification.primary-token.secret= myTokenSecret
```

These ***push-notification properties*** are optional and are used to enable push notifications for Azure App Configuration.

- It allows the application to receive notifications if there are any changes in configuration values and it will automatically update its configuration.
- If you don't specify these properties, push notifications will not be enabled.
- These properties are used to authenticate your application with Azure App Configuration, so that it can receive push notifications when the configuration changes.
- The push-notification properties can also be used later when you need them.

So, you can use the following properties without specifying push-notification properties:

```
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].connection-string= ${AppConfigurationConnectionString}
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].monitoring.enabled= true
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].monitoring.refresh-interval= 30d
spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].monitoring.triggers[0].key= sentinel

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include= appconfiguration-refresh
```